# Compact and non-compact curves in the plane

Tags: real-analysis

I want to find compact and non-compact curves in the plane:

MY attempt" Suppose $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ is continous function. Put $C = \{ (x, f(x) ) \} $. Then $C$ is closed. IS it bounded? If so, Then we can say that

$$\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y = x^2 \} $$
is compact curve.

If we let $f$ be non continuous, then $C$ is not closed, hence not compact.

Is this correct?

Comment: If the domain of $f$ is unbounded, then $C$ is certainly not bounded.

Comment: The graph of $y=x^2$ is certainly not bounded, unless you restrict the domain to a bounded subset. If the bounded subset is closed too (hence copmact), then the curve will be compact if $f$ is continuous. For an example of a non-compact curve, you can take $f(x)=1/x, \quad f(0)=0$ in the interval $[0,1]$. Note that  the function fails to be continuous, which allows the unboundedness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We begin by establishing the following theorems:

*Thm. 1* In $\mathbb{R}^n$, a closed, bounded set is compact.

*Thm. 2* The continuous image of a compact set is compact.

Hence given any continuous function $f:C\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ where $C$ is a compact set, then $f(C)$ is compact. If $C\cong S^1$ then the curve is closed. If $C\cong \mathbb{R}$ then it is not compact and if $C\cong [0,1]$ then it is compact.